# modify function to access private variable from outside a class

Tags: javascript

I want to modify the getSecret function to enable the private variable 'secret' to be accessed from outside the 'bestfriends' class.

Any ideas?

```
function bestfriends(name1, name2) {
this.friend1 = name1;
this.friend2 = name2;
var secret = "Hakuna Matata!";
console.log (this.friend1 + ' and ' + this.friend2 + ' are the best of friends! ');
}

bestfriends.prototype.getSecret = function() {
   return secret
}

var timon_pubmaa = bestfriends('timon', 'pumbaa');

var timon_pumbaa_secret = getSecret();

console.log(timon_pumbaa_secret);
```

Comment: 1. `var timon_pubmaa = new bestfriends('timon', 'pumbaa');` 2. `var timon_pumbaa_secret = timon_pubmaa.getSecret();` 3. `return this.secret` 4. `this.secret = ...` Or move the `getSecret` implementation inside the constructor and use a closure.

Comment: You can't. You can either make the property public or expose a getter from the same scope, but you can't post-modify access to private scope.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the `new` keyword with `bestfriends`.

`getSecret` should be called on the instance like `timon_pubmaa.getSecret()`.

Your `secret` variable is local to the constructor, it can't be accessed from the method. To achieve that, you can create a closure and return your consturctor, and within the closure you can create variables which will be private.

```
var bestfriends = (function () {

    var secret; // private variable

    function bestfriends(name1, name2) {
        this.friend1 = name1;
        this.friend2 = name2;
        secret = "Hakuna Matata!";
        console.log(this.friend1 + ' and ' + this.friend2 + ' are the best of friends! ');
    }

    bestfriends.prototype.getSecret = function () {
        return secret
    }

    return bestfriends;

})();

var timon_pubmaa = new bestfriends('timon', 'pumbaa');
var timon_pumbaa_secret = timon_pubmaa.getSecret();
console.log(timon_pumbaa_secret); // Hakuna Matata!
```

Comment: When I enter this code above, I get "ReferenceError: getSecret is not defined"

Comment: If the `secret` variable is static (accessible to the whole class), you should not initialise it from the constructor..

Comment: I've gone and added the secret variable at the top of the code, but I still get the same: "ReferenceError: getSecret is not defined"